# How to call render method of a cell view from the editor view upon change event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backgrid

I have the backbone view like

```
var EditorView = Backbone.View.extend({
  //.....
});

var CellView = Backbone.View.extend({
  editor: EditorView
  initialize: function (optionValues,multiple) {
  //....
  this.listenTo(this.editor,'change',this.render);
 }
  //.....
});
```

But the above only listen to event only once, Not twice.

How should i use `listenTo` function so that view always listens to the model's events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening on an event from a constructor of a view. `EditorView` is a constructor function and not an instance of the view.

You should either use global messenging to communicate between views:

```
var EditorView = Backbone.View.extend({
  //.....
  change : function() {
    Backbone.trigger('editor:change');
  }
});

var CellView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function (optionValues,multiple) {
  this.listenTo(Backbone,'editor:change',this.render);
 }
});
```

Or pass the editor's instance in the creation of the cell view:

```
var CellView = Backbon.View.extend({
  initialize: function( options ) {
    this.editor = options.editor;
    this.listenTo( this.editor, 'change', this.render );
  }
});
```

I think the global messenging style is clearer and offers more flexibility.